# Egress TLS Origination works for one domain but not for other

Tags: ssl, istio

I’m want to do TLS origination to an external service and I’m following Istio’s [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/) to configure it.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: edition-cnn-com
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  ports:
  - number: 80
name: http-port
protocol: HTTP
  - number: 443
name: https-port-for-tls-origination
protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: edition-cnn-com
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  http:
  - match:
- port: 80
route:
- destination:
    host: edition.cnn.com
    subset: tls-origination
    port:
      number: 443
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: edition-cnn-com
spec:
  host: edition.cnn.com
  subsets:
  - name: tls-origination
trafficPolicy:
  loadBalancer:
    simple: ROUND_ROBIN
  portLevelSettings:
  - port:
      number: 443
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE # initiates HTTPS when accessing edition.cnn.com
```

The above configuration works for [edition.cnn.com](http://edition.cnn.com) domain but if I change this domain to something like [httpbin.stackbox.xyz](https://httpbin.stackbox.xyz), it doesn’t work. Why is it working for one domain but not for other?

Note, it can be accessed from outside as using HTTPS

```
curl -i https://httpbin.stackbox.xyz/ip
```

Comment: What is the error you occurs, 503 service unavailable? Do you have global mtls enabled or disabled?

Comment: You are missing the gateway